# replace jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

How to use bootstrap instead of "jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" and "jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js" ?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 requires jQuery. Though I'm not sure the mobile version is supported.

Comment: @Ouroborus i need to replace the jQuery.css to Bootstrap.ss , any version of bootstrap